# How to add objects within another array of object at alternate position?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, reactjs, react-redux

I am working on a react component. Requirement is to add a new object at alternate position within array of object e.g. below:

```
arr1 = [{test: 1},{test: 2},{test: 3},{test: 4}]
```

expected output:

```
arr1 = [{test: 1},{dummy:1},{test: 2},{dummy:1},{test: 3},{dummy:1},{test: 4}]
```

is there a way to do the same in es6?

Comment: [...arr1, ...dummy].sort(yourSortFunction)

Answer (score 5):

For getting your *desired* array, you could make of use the `concat` method in combination with `reduce`.

```js
var array = [{test: 1},{test: 2},{test: 3},{test: 4}];
var result = array.reduce((res, item) => res.concat(item, {dummy: 1}), []).slice(0, -1);
    
console.log(result);
```

Since this adds `{dummy: 1}` object after each element from your array, just use

```
.slice(0, -1)
```

to add one *exception* for the *last* element from your *given* array.

If you want to modify the *original* array *inplace*, you could use `splice` method.

```js
var array = [{test: 1},{test: 2},{test: 3},{test: 4}];
for(i = 0;i < array.length - 1; i = i + 2){
  array.splice(i + 1, 0, {dummy: 1});
}
console.log(array);
```

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen, I added one solution if he wants to modify the original array inplace.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use map if I can. It is easier to understand and maintain.

So first create an array of array and then flatten it a single array with flat.

```js
let arr1 = [{test: 1},{test: 2},{test: 3},{test: 4}]

arr1 = arr1.map(item=>[item,{dummy:1}]).flat().slice(0, -1)

console.log(arr1);
```

Answer (score 1):

To modify the original array (instead of creating an new one), you can first generate the indexes at which the new items need to be inserted, and then use `Array.prototype.splice()` :

```js
const a = [{test: 1}, {test: 2}, {test: 3}, {test: 4}];

Array.from({length: a.length - 1}, (_, i) => i * 2 + 1)
     .forEach(i => a.splice(i, 0, {dummy: 1}));

console.log(a);
```